# Isn't meta effect more worth than a bounty?

Tags: discussion

If somebody has a well written question and not gaining enough attention, Linking the question to meta citing any simple reasons such as '*why is my question not receiving enough attention though it covers all requisition?*' Will give more attention and reputation than offering a bounty gives. Why would anybody offer a bounty citing *this question has not received enough attention*? Shouldn't we restrict posts linking in meta?

Comment: It's usually fairly obvious to see when people are looking for upvotes.  Constructively asking how to improve your question has never been and never will be off topic on meta. Please don't restrict post linking on meta.

Comment: Restricting linking wouldn't actually do anything. It is trivial to look at someone's profile and find the post they're talking about. Yes, Meta directs attention to your posts. I don't understand why you think this is a problem. Moreover, most of the attention you'll get from the Meta effect is votes and edits, not answers. Meta participants aren't necessarily experts  on whatever the topic of your question is, and if the question is really time-consuming enough to answer that you feel you need a bounty, a Meta audience probably won't take the time to answer without it, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why would anybody offer a bounty citing this question has not received
>   enough attention?

Well they do. There's usually around 400 bounty questions open at a time and since we aren't overrun with, "Why isn't my question getting attention?" type posts, I don't think this is a real problem.

The Meta effect gets a question more attention but that attention is:

- Not necessarily positive attention
- Attention from a much smaller group than the main site

Someone getting a ton of up votes by posting their question on Meta isn't really common. But more importantly, the point of a bounty is to get answers, not rep, and the smaller pool of people on Meta means you're less likely to get the attention of someone who can and will answer your question.

Comment: *Attention from a much smaller group than the main site* a much smaller, and more critical group.

Comment: @Glorfindel Also a group that takes unkindly to complaining about downvotes, or edits, or pointlessly making a meta post because you want your question answered.

Comment: @Magisch Yes, I answered this on the assumption that the OP meant that someone would at least pretend they were seeking help with their question's quality. If someone posted and actually said they were trying to get up votes or answers, they'd get destroyed.

Answer (score 11):

Meta is a fickle beast. Posting a question results in more attention, but what you seem to forget is that attention is not limited to positive attention (like it mostly is with a bounty). If you post your question on meta, more often then not it can:

- Get closed
- Get deleted
- Get downvoted heavily

What usually doesn't happen often as the result of meta attention is your question getting *answered*, you know, the primary and stated purpose of why someone would put a bounty on a question.